# Simplificar requisição Date via json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, getjson

será que consigo retornar o valor de uma variável fora do bloco "no caso seria as variáveis **serverTime** e **off**", digo pra eu poder utilizar em outra função ou no meu código html.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onload = function() {
    var dateHeader = xmlhttp.getResponseHeader('Date');

    // Basta armazenar a hora atual no dispositivo para fins de exibição 
    deviceTime = moment();

    // Transforme o campo do cabeçalho "Data:" em um objeto "momento",
    serverTime = moment(new Date(dateHeader)); // Read

    // Armazene as diferenças entre a hora do dispositivo e a hora do servidor
    off = serverTime.diff(moment());

    return
}


xmlhttp.open("HEAD", window.location.href);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Somente uma observação, estou usando este script para pegar a hora atual do servidor.

Obrigado!!!!

Comment: Mas as variáveis foram declaradas globalmente, já pode utilizá-las em qualquer lugar do código.

Comment: então, isso que não estou entendendo, testei um   `alert(serverTime);` após a linha xmlhttp.send(); e não está passando.

Comment: E o que mostrou no alert?

Comment: Se eu coloco ele dentro do scopo ele funciona normal mostrando a data belezinha, porém fora ele não mostra nada, dei um f12, estou tentando entender os erros aqui

Comment: Então, é pq o objeto **XMLHttpRequest()** gera um código assíncrono, ou seja, depende do retorno do servidor que pode ser imediato, demorado ou até nunca ocorrer, para devolver a resposta.

Comment: tu sabe me dizer se tem alguma outra forma de fazer isso ?

Comment: haha fiz diferente, chamei minha outra função dentro do escopo, ali antes do return. Aí funfou direitinho. De toda forma obrigado pela atenção. Tudibão!!!! Abraço!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que encontrei, foi chamar minha outra função **dentro do escopo**, sendo assim minha outra função conseguiu receber o valor de **serverTime**.

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onload = function() {
    var dateHeader = xmlhttp.getResponseHeader('Date');

    // Basta armazenar a hora atual no dispositivo para fins de exibição 
    deviceTime = moment();

    // Transforme o campo do cabeçalho "Data:" em um objeto "momento",
    serverTime = moment(new Date(dateHeader)); // Read

    // Armazene as diferenças entre a hora do dispositivo e a hora do servidor
    off = serverTime.diff(moment());

    //chamei a função aqui antes do retorno, e assim ela enxergou a var serverTime;
    metal(); 

    return
}
xmlhttp.open("HEAD", window.location.href);
xmlhttp.send();
```